# Performance tips for c# function

Tags: c#, performance

Looking for any tips on how to speed up/rewrite the following function. The array is ordered so was thinking could this be replaced with BinarySearch but as I need to return the nearest indexes it might not be appropriate.

For the purpose of this investigation assume istart = 0 and iend = Array Length -1

```
/// <summary>
    /// Given an array "xx" of length "n", and given a value "x", this routine
    /// returns a value "j" such that "x" is between xx(j) and xx(j+1).  
    /// xx must be monotonic, either increasing or decreasing.  j=istart or j=n is
    /// returned to indicate that x is out of range.
    /// Modified to set the start and end points by "istart" and "iend" 
    /// </summary>
    public static int Locate(double[] xx, int n, int istart, int iend, double x)
    {

        if (istart > iend || x < xx[istart])
        {
            return istart;
        }
        else if (x > xx[iend])
        {
            return iend;
        }

        int mid;
        while (istart +1 < iend)
        {
            mid = (istart + iend) >> 1;
            
            if (x < xx[mid])
            {
                iend = mid ;
            }
            else
            {
                istart = mid ;
            }
        }

        if (iend >= n || xx[iend] != x)
        {
            return iend -1;
        }
        else 
            return iend;


    }
```

Comment: what is the *purpose* of this optimzation? Do you measured the code to identify that it runs slow or are you just haunting for potential problems? Do you have a *specific problem* with this code?

Comment: Is `x` contained in `xx`?

Comment: Your code is not readable, it takes a long time to understand it, you shouldn't use names for the parameters xx, x, istart.
It should look like this:
xx - collectionInputValues
n -expectcollectionLength
Also method name nothing says anything about what this method does.
Let me know when you improve it.

Comment: Don't use `>> 1` to divide by two - it's completely unnecessary; the compiler will optimise this for you. Also: "thinking could this be replaced with BinarySearch" - this looks like it already IS a binary search.

Comment: An obvious optimisation is to check `if (x == xx[mid])` inside the loop and return `mid` if so.

Comment: " ... how to speed up/rewrite the following function" — Does the method need to be sped up or does it need to be rewritten?  Why are you looking to potentially rewrite it; to speed it up or some other reason?  It's easier and clearer if you state the specific problem you are trying to solve.  Otherwise, for open-ended feedback ("tips") see [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Yes when the array is largish 100K + doubles it takes quite a bit of time to search the array.

Comment: @SilnyToJa Agreed, this is legacy code from the days of Pentium cpu's and cd-roms

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews  It was deemed less risky to speed it up but should no obvious gains be made a rewrite will occur!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Array.BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=net-6.0#system-array-binarysearch-1(-0()-system-int32-system-int32-0))

> The index of the specified value in the specified array, if value is found; otherwise, a negative number. If value is not found and value is less than one or more elements in array, the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value. If value is not found and value is greater than all elements in array, the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of (the index of the last element plus 1). If this method is called with a non-sorted array, the return value can be incorrect and a negative number could be returned, even if value is present in array.

So you should be able to replace your function with

```
var index = Array.BinarySearch(xx, istart, iend - istart + 1, x);
if(index < 0){
   index = ~index -1 // take the bitwise complement and subtract one to get the index of the value before x
```

Note that you might need to do some additional checks for cases like empty arrays, or if x is smaller or larger than all values, since it looks like some specific output is required for such cases.

> such that "x" is between xx(j) and xx(j+1)

The 'between' is a bit ambiguous here since it does not specify if the range is inclusive or not. You kind of have to assume it is inclusive, since x would not be part of the non-inclusive set x to x+n.

Also note that the parameters are kind of weird, The length is not needed, since arrays know they own length. And when specifying intervals of arrays you usually use index + length, and not start + end, since there may be some confusion if you should include the end-index or not.

As a last point, whenever dealing with performance, *measure*. Benchmark.net is the gold standard, but a stopwatch might do in a pinch. A profiler is also helpful to hint at where the problem might be.

Comment: Just for posterity the speed of BinarySearch to the original function was comparable. ~60ms to search an ordered array of 10000000 elements. I am accepting this answer as I believe this approach is far more readable. Thanks!